# Putty closed down on login

Tags: ssh

I have problem with login in into my dedicated server.

After logining in into server I got  putty message "Connection closed by remote host".

The error in var/log/auth.log is:

```
[18064]: Accepted publickey for root from 37.47.15.47 port 9674 ssh2: RSA 24:da:ae:f4:ee:53:e1:3f:b3:8a:ac:e9:1f:bd:02:a2
Sep  6 13:03:02 ns326875 sshd[18064]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  6 13:03:02 ns326875 sshd[18064]: error: PAM: pam_open_session(): Module is unknown
```

How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems was in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

I needed to comment out the following line:

```
# session    required   pam_chroot.so
```

Seems that by accident I have removed this module.